# Prove that the sum of the digits of $9^n$ is not equal to $9$ for $n \ge 3$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

It may seem really easy to solve but almost all of us are stuck on this one.

Seems really weird:

> Prove that, for all $3\leqslant n$, $S(9^n)\not=9$.
>
> $S(n)$ is the sum of digits of $n$ base $10$.

َAlso, there's no need to check for odd $n$ because in that case the solution is as follows:

- First of all it's clear that $S(n)$ is divisible by $9$ so if it's not $9$ we're done.
- Furthermore, if $n$ is odd, the rightmost digit of $9^n$ is $9$, and there's at least one other non-zero digit, so sum of digits of $n$ is more than $9$, and that's it.

But for even $n$ I'm seriously stuck.

Comment: could you clarify what is $S$?

Comment: Yep I'm sorry I'll point it out

Comment: It's true for n=2.

Comment: Sorry it was for bigger than 2 the equality case wasn't in the condition

Comment: You could still add a few worked examples of $n$ you have checked to the question  - if you had done this in the first place the bounds typo would have been more evident.

Comment: it is easy if $n$ is odd (just look at the last digit)

Comment: I actually intended to write the program to check if it's true for small values but then noted that the density of counterexamples is incredibly low. Also note that the case that n is odd is easily solved so just do it for even n.

Comment: See https://www.jstor.org/stable/2695428?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents

Comment: Try using induction to prove that for any positive integer m , 9^(m+2) cannot have digits summing up to 9

Comment: You mean for $n$ strictly greater than 2, because for $n=2$ is clearly false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adapting from @ACheca [suggested paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2695428?read-now=1&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) "The Decimal Expansions of Powers of 9" by Sapir, Lossers & Montgomery (independently) 1999:

First as stated note that for $\underline{\text{odd }n>1}$, since $9^n\equiv 9 \bmod 10$ we know that the last digit is $9$ and since $9^n> 9$ there are other non-zero digits, so $S(9^n)>9$

Thus for $\underline{\text{even }n}$ we are looking to show that $S(81^k)>9,$ where $\underline{k=n/2>1}$

Let $M(a)$ be the value $(a \bmod 99999)$ with $0\leq M(a)\leq 99999$. Then we can show that $S(M(a))\leq S(a)$ by the following process:

- Find $M(a)$ from $a$ by taking block of 5 digits and summing the blocks. This process is invariant $\bmod 99999$ and repeated as necessary will produce $M(a)$. However this summing process never increases the digit sum - any carrying effects only reduce the digit sum. Thus $S(M(a))\leq S(a)$.

Now the values of $M(81^k)$ cycle through the following $30$ values:
$C =(81,6561,31446,$ $47151,19269,60804,$ $25173,39033,61704,$ $98073,43992,63387,$ $34398,86265,87534,$ $90324,16317,21690,$ $56907,9513,70560,$ $15417,48789,51948,$ $7830,34236,73143,$ $24642,96021,77778)$. By inspection the digit sum of all of these except the first are greater than $9$.

Thus:

- For $k \not\equiv 1 \bmod 30$, we have $S(81^k)\geq S(M(81^k))>9$
- For $k\equiv 1 \bmod 30$ , we have $81^k\equiv 81 \bmod 100$ and recalling that $k>1$ we have $81^k > 81$ and there are other non-zero digits, so for this case also $S(81^k)>9$

... proving the case $n$ even also.

Comment: @timon92 no, this is specifically looking to generate the mod 99999 values, because those relate to the digit sum.

Comment: Actually, that's really great. BTW I'll appreciate any solutions without checking 30 values by hand.(If any exists)

Comment: @AryanHemmati I should go and check my (Excel generated) values against the paper... yes, they match,